# Why does the compiler prints the following code in reverse order? (I'm new to programming)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a=2;
    printf("%d %d %d", a, a++, a++);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

**4 3 2**

For additional information, I'm using Visual Studio with gcc compiler installed.

Comment: The order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified. Your code could as well display `2 3 4`. That being said: never write nonsense code like this.

Comment: It is giving you a lesson on why not to do multiple things on one line.  Write simple, clear code.